# generate sequential value across multiple layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, for-loop, qgis-custom-function, sequential

Running QGIS 3.16, relative beginner in q

I am trying to make an auto-generated id number that:

1. is a sequential integer, starting at 1
2. can be used in 2 or more different layers without
   duplication
3. Is auto-filled in the table when a new feature is added to any layer

The purpose is to be able to have a single dataset that is split into points lines and polygons that has a single unique ID that is easy to read for output to printed (MS Word or Excel format) reports. For example:

Site 1 - Point (a location of an incident, a findspot of a coin)
Site 2 - Line (a section of road the incident took place on, an iron age ditch)
Site 3 - Polygon (Damaged sections of road, a Roman fort)

Or to be able to make a photographic register that can be easily gathered in the field with Qfield (set up as 3 relationship-linked tables to the points lines and polygons above set up as shown here: https://qfield.org/docs/prepare/add-1-n-pictures.html) then collated and exported to look like this:

[image: A mock photo register showing how data is collected in the field, with multiple photos of a single feature, photos recorded out of sequence and manual notes]

I've tried a UUID, which is fine for a backup when setting up the relationship but, is too long to be used in a report.

I tried an SQL query based on a reference table called "Numbers" which is a no geometry shapefile with a single field "id" containing integers 1 to 7:

```
Default value of PolySites.SiteID 
= "Numbers.id" 
Where "Numbers.id" =/= "PolySites.id" 
AND "Numbers.id" =/= "PointSites.id"
AND "Numbers.ID" =/= "LineSites.id"
```

But this returned Parser Errors:
syntax error, unexpected EQ
syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting $end
syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_COLUMN_REF, expecting $end
syntax error, unexpected DIV
syntax error, unexpected DIV

Then I tried:

```
array_find(("Numbers.id"), NOT "PolySites.id" OR NOT "PointSites.id" OR NOT "LineSites.id")
```

But:
Eval Error: Field 'Numbers.id' not found
(Numbers.id is a valid field in a valid table in the project)

Then:

```
 get_feature_by_id("Numbers.id", NOT "PolySites.id" OR NOT "PointSites.id" OR NOT "LineSites.id")
```

Eval Error: Field 'Numbers.id' not found

So far, I think a function to make a for loop is my best bet. I have this saved in the function editor as the file "sequential numbers"
Im a beginner so do not know how to make a function set out in the editor work as a default value.

Should I be using some function to concatenate the existing values and create a new featureclass with the concatenated list, then check against that in the function below and get rid of it afterwards?

How do I call the function in the default value for the field?

````
#start at 1, then check polys and points for a number. 
#if number is not used, update ID to that number 
#if number is used, add 1 to the number and check again

```python
def make_sequential_numbers ():
    notenumber = 1
    for number in notenumber:
        if number () in 'PointSites.id' or 'PolySites.id' or 'LineSites.id':
            notenumber = notenumber + 1
        else:
            notenumber = notenumber
    return notenumber
````

Theres no syntax error but it does not work. I added "notenumber" as the default value for the id field in the points, lines and polys layers, but nothing is happening

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'll update the post